# Tried installing CLI for Tailwind, but error shows when I input the second command

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I ran `npx tailwindcss` init in the terminal following this link: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

See error log below. I am not really well-versed in node.js but this is the first time I encountered an error when running nodejs commands. Hope someone can help!

````
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'exec',
0 verbose cli   '--',
0 verbose cli   'tailwindcss',
0 verbose cli   'init'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.3.1
2 info using node@v16.14.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 4ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 4ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 3ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\torre\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\torre\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 13ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 14ms
19 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
20 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
21 timing npm:load:display Completed in 5ms
22 verbose logfile C:\Users\torre\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-19T07_06_52_911Z-debug-0.log
23 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 5ms
24 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 1ms
25 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 26ms
27 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
28 timing command:exec Completed in 9ms
29 verbose stack Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
29 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
29 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
29 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
30 verbose cwd C:\Users\torre
31 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22000
32 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "exec" "--" "tailwindcss" "init"
33 verbose node v16.14.0
34 verbose npm  v8.3.1
35 error code ENOENT
36 error syscall spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;
37 error path C:\Users\torre
38 error errno -4058
39 error enoent spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
40 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
40 error enoent
41 verbose exit -4058
42 timing npm Completed in 381ms
43 verbose code -4058
44 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
44 error     C:\Users\torre\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-19T07_06_52_911Z-debug-0.log```
````

Answer (score 0):

try using the latest version of node.js and npm